# my web have lag when load data from server

Tags: angularjs

I tell you my problem.

I'm working with angularjs, and routes (ngRoute).
So, when I open a view, this it have a delay, because load data from my server on controller.

I do it with $http.

Code:

```js
$http.post('controllers/communeCTRL.php',{'option' : 'getAllCommunes'})
  .success(function(results){
    $scope.comunas = results;
  });
```

This it returns me 350 data rows

Comment: Well, yes, it probably won't be instantaneous if it has to roundtrip to the server. What do you want us to do about it?

Comment: I need not have delayed the web

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want the data to be ready when you enter the view.
Take a look at the docs for  [resolve](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider#when).

> resolve - {Object.=} - An optional map of
>   dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of
>   these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to
>   be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is
>   instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the
>   values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess
>   event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the
>   $routeChangeError event is fired. The map object is:....

so essentially you have to resolve the call to the server in the route config. If the `http` call fails you will not enter the view if it success you have your data ready in the controller by injecting the key of the resolve.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was what I needed